# boost::filesystem::rename: Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I'm renaming a file using boost::filesystem, and sometimes the target file will exist. According to the boost documentation here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Non-member-functions

> template 
>   void rename(const Path1& from_p, const
>   Path2& to_p); Requires:
>   Path1::external_string_type and
>   Path2::external_string_type are the
>   same type.
>
> Effects: Renames from_p to to_p, as if
>   by POSIX rename().
>
> Postconditions: !exists(from_p) &&
>   exists(to_p), and the contents and
>   attributes of the file originally
>   named from_p are otherwise unchanged.
>
> [Note: If from_p and to_p resolve to
>   the same file, no action is taken.
>   Otherwise, **if to_p resolves to an
>   existing file, it is removed**. A
>   symbolic link is itself renamed,
>   rather than the file it resolves to
>   being renamed. -- end note]

(my emphasis)

When testing this code compiled via MS Visual Studio 2008 on XP SP3, the rename throws boost::filesystem::filesystem_error with the message:

Cannot create a file when that file already exists

I note this has been raised in a bug report:
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2866

... but claims to be closed in Boost 1.41.0 and I'm using Boost 1.42.0.

Am I doing something wrong here or should I just revert to std::rename?

I haven't tested this on Linux yet so don't know if the problem exists there too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it was fixed, but only in the sandbox "V3" version of Boost.Filesystem, which is not in the mainline Boost releases yet.

I tested on Boost 1.43.0 on Linux with the same results - in fact the bug report points out the offending code, which explicitly checks for existence on POSIX and throws the exception.  It's possible this was done originally because `MoveFile` on Windows exhibits the same behavior?  In the sandbox V3 version, rename will call `MoveFileEx` on Windows and `std::rename` on POSIX, and allows overwriting an existing file.

I suppose you could work around it by calling `boost::filesystem::remove` on the target before calling `boost::filesystem::rename`, depending upon whether your program needs the operation to be atomic or not.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised the fix hadn't made it out to the wider world. 

For the app I'm developing I probably will use remove/rename, but as you say, if I needed something atomic I'd be stuffed.

Comment: If you are working with older software, the first "V3" release of Boost.Filesystem is 1.46.0 (see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/filesystem/doc/release_history.html)